# Кастомное подключение к Redis из Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, redis

**Задача:** Описать модель джанго, способную обращаться к ключу Redis при обращении к модели. Это подключение предназначено только для работы с моделями и в других механизмах django не используется.

**Вопрос:** Где и как в Django описать объект подключения к Redis было бы правильнее, чтобы его переиспользовать и не плодить сущности?
Первая идея была - сделать это в settings.

*settings.py*

```
...
REDIS_CONNECTION = redis.Redis("127.0.0.1", 6379, 1)
...
```

Попробовал так, но чёт IDE ругается,  думаю, лучше спросить:

*models.py*

```
from django.conf import settings
...
class TaskStatusModel(models.Model):
    status = (('Ошибка', 'E'), ('В процессе', 'P'), ('Завершена', 'F'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Имя задачи")
    redis_key = models.UUIDField(verbose_name='Ключ задачи', default=uuid.uuid4())
    permanent_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=status, default="P")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        settings.REDIS_CONNECTION.set(str(self.redis_key), 0)
...
```

Comment: Создайте новый py-файл, назовите например redis и поместите в него. Уж точно не в settings и не в models

Comment: если это будет отдельный файл, то при каждом использовании его надо будет заново импортировать и будет создаваться новое подключение. так? В то время как при записи в settings, объект Redis уже будет висеть в пространстве имен и будет использоваться один и тот же экземпляр без пересоздания подключения. Это догадка, поправьте, если я что-то не верно понимаю.

Comment: Нет, он импортируется ровно один раз и подключение будет тоже ровно одно. Все следующие импорты переиспользуют самый первый импорт